# ASP.Net Treeview: Strange postback behavior

Tags: asp.net, treeview, postback, subclassing

I have a ASP.NET treeview populated with custom treenodes (ExtensionRangeTreeNode subclassed from TreeNode).
On postback the treeview is populated with TreeNodes, not my custom treenode class.

What's up with this?

Thanks,
BP

Answer (score 1):

This [forum entry](http://forums.asp.net/p/1109208/1713613.aspx#1713613) may answer the question :

Basically, it is said a custom treeview control has to be used. CreateNode function must be overriden to instanciate the right TreeNode type. Here, it would be ExtensionRangeTreeNode instead of "CustomTreeNode".

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override TreeNode CreateNode()
    {
        return new CustomTreeNode(this, false);
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to add the ExtensionRangeTreeNode(Treeview treeview, bool isRoot) constructor signature to your current ExtensionRangeTreeNode implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your particular code, I can only assume that you custom TreeNode is not using ViewState. This would explain why it is not getting populated on postback.

Comment: I thought of that. However, attempting to reload viewstate on postback yields this error:
"Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request."

BP

Answer (score 0):

DoesExtensionRangeTreeNode fully handle saving itself to the viewstate fully? If so, can you cast the returned nodes to that type?